# Issues with for loops

Tags: python

I'm trying to learn python with jetbrains and I'm really struggling with for loops.  I wish I could explain all my general issues but its highly situational, I can't remember exactly what my last issue was and normall I can guess them correctly after failing.  Here I have a syntax issue on lines 21 and 23.  What am I doing wrong?

```
1   user_input = input('Enter cells: ')
2   # print game
3   print('---------')
4   print('| ' + user_input[0] + ' ' + user_input[1] + ' ' + user_input[2] + ' |')
5   print('| ' + user_input[3] + ' ' + user_input[4] + ' ' + user_input[5] + ' |')
6   print('| ' + user_input[6] + ' ' + user_input[7] + ' ' + user_input[8] + ' |')
7   print('---------')
8   # separate winning lines
9   row_1 = user_input[0] + user_input[1] + user_input[2]
10  row_2 = user_input[3] + user_input[4] + user_input[5]
11  row_3 = user_input[6] + user_input[7] + user_input[8]
12  col_1 = user_input[0] + user_input[3] + user_input[6]
13  col_2 = user_input[1] + user_input[4] + user_input[7]
14  col_3 = user_input[2] + user_input[5] + user_input[8]
15  dia_1 = user_input[0] + user_input[4] + user_input[8]
16  dia_2 = user_input[6] + user_input[4] + user_input[2]
17  lines = [row_1, row_2, row_3, col_1, col_2, col_3, dia_1, dia_2]
18  # evaluate results
19  x_counter = 0
20  o_counter = 0
21  for x in lines if x == 'X':
22      x_counter += 1 
23  for o in lines if o == 'O':
24      o_counter += 1
25  if x_counter - o_counter >=2: print('Impossible')
26  if o_counter - x_counter >=2: print('Impossible')
27  if 'XXX' and 'OOO' in lines: print('Impossible')
28  elif 'XXX' in lines: print('X wins')
29  elif 'OOO' in lines: print('O wins')
30  elif '_' in lines: print('Game not finished')
31  else: print('Draw')
```

Comment: `for x in lines if x == 'X':` is simply incorrect. Why do you think you can use `if x == 'X'` here? Here is the [relevant documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement)

Comment: don't think you can do if statements with your for loop like that. I've only seen it like that with list comprehensions/generators

Comment: You should review the for loop syntax.  An if condition is not part of the syntax (i.e. should follow the start of the loop).

Comment: In general, start by learning the python syntax, and I would recommend using a good IDE like PyCharm (has a free version). codecademy has a good course, or simply start with the first search result for "python for loops" https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp

Comment: `if x == 'X':` should be on the next line after `for x in lines:`

Comment: @Wade PyCharm == JetBrains

Comment: Yeah, also, I would recommend *not using and IDE at all* when starting out with Python. But this is all a matter of opinion.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga There simply isn't information in my brain to tell me I can't use it that way I'm just learning.  I don't know the right way to do it that's what I'm asking

Comment: @Barmar  Bingo there's what I was doing wrong

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga  Not random.  They are educated guesses based on what I find through google.  It's rarely crystal clear enough for me to know exactly what I'm doing wrong so I have to learn some by trial and error.  Not sure what else I can do

Comment: Read through this: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/ trial and error is not the way for basic syntax